# Can you select more than one Id?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<p class="Links" onclick="window.location.href = 'file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/Online%20Store.html#Residential'; document.getElementById('residence1, residence2, residence3').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('Commercial').style.display='none';">
Residential
</p>
```

I am trying but I fail to select more than one id using this method. Is my method correct or wrong?

Comment: No, Instead use `querySelectorAll(#id1,#id2,)`

Comment: why dont you make it easy on yourself and just have a class which wraps all Residential and one which wraps all Commercial?

Comment: i am sorry but i don't know how to use the "wrap" thing. I am a beginner right now it has just been a week or so. Can you elaborate on "a class which wraps all Residiential and one which wraps all Commercial?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to collect a bunch of elements based on more than one selector, `querySelectorAll` is your best friend.

Unlike jQuery, querySelectorAll returns a `NodeList` type of object, similar to an array. To execute anything on each of the collection's members, you need to iterate over the collection yourself, e.g. using `forEach`:

```html
<p onclick="document.querySelectorAll('#residence1, #residence2, #residence3').forEach(el => el.style.display='block')">
Residential
</p>

<div id="residence1" style="display: none;">residence1</div>
<div id="residence2" style="display: none;">residence2</div>
<div id="residence3" style="display: none;">residence3</div>
```

Please note that this addresses only your immediate syntactical needs; it merely fixes your (bad) approach.

What you should instead/not do:

- NEVER work with element.style - use CSS classes, or in case of showing/hiding elements, use the builtin universal `hidden` attribute of HTML.

Example:

Instead of doing

```
element.style.display = 'block'
```

rather make sure your CSS has a class `.hidden`defined

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

and then to show an element, remove the class from it, and to hide it, add the class:

```
element.classList.remove('hidden'); // show
element.classList.add('hidden'); // hide
```

As stated before, specifically for showing/hiding, the most simple thing to do is toggle the boolean `hidden` property of the element:

```
element.hidden = false; // show
element.hidden = true; // hide
```

or, if you prefer attributes over properties:

```
element.removeAttribute('hidden'); // show
element.setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden'); // hide
```

Also, as other have already stated, if you need to toggle the visibility of a whole collection of element, the best way is to give all those elements the same CSS class name (which makes it much easier to select):

```html
<p onclick="document.querySelectorAll('.residence').forEach(el => el.hidden = !el.hidden)">
Residential
</p>

<div class="residence" hidden>residence1</div>
<div class="residence" hidden>residence2</div>
<div class="residence" hidden>residence3</div>
```

I've also added the capability to rather toggle the visibility of the `.residence` div elements by not assigning a literal value to `el.hidden`, but instead taking what's already in `el.hidden` and inverting the boolean using the **not operator** `!`.

Comment: can you explain more about `.hidden` i have not used it before so your information could surely be of great help

Comment: @0Bionic https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden Or was your question about the CSS class?

Comment: @0Bionic Think about your last comment. Is there anything I, **or any other person on this planet**, can take from it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to this code:

```
document.getElementById('residence1, residence2, residence3').style.display='block'
```

You are able to select multiple elements with [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which will return a [node list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) that you can iterate over with [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

So, for your example, you could do the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#residence1', '#residence2', '#residence3').forEach(el => el.style.display='block')
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems like an easy solution but i don't wanna be a man who just relies on "what is in the book" so, do you mind if you tell me what it means by "el" in the code "el.style.display='block' ?

Comment: `el` is the current element that `.forEach()` is iterating over, `el.style.display='block'` is what you want to do with said element. I linked the method above in case you were are familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use query selectors to get multiple elements at once. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) page out to get a brief list of how to use `querySelectorAll()`.

In your case you can simply use

`querySelectorAll("#id1, #id2, #id3")` which will return an array of all the elements matching these id's